# Regex: how to handle two groups with the same name?

Tags: python, regex

I have strings with some daily times, which are given in two possible ways:

1. `(...) 1100-1300 DAILY (...)`
2. `(...) DAILY 1100-1300 (...)`

I want to read the time. Unfortunately I cannot do this like below, because I have the same group used twice (which is unacceptable), so this throws an error:

```
import re

string = "TIME SCHEDULE: 1100-1300 DAILY"
pattern = "((?P<time>\d{4}-\d{4}) DAILY|DAILY (?P<time>\d{4}-\d{4}))"
match = re.search(pattern, string)
time = match.group("time")
```

What I could do here, is to create two separate groups (`time1` and `time2`), then check if any of them is present in the match... Possible, but dirty and not scalable (what if I had more than 2 groups?).

How can I approach it **without use of non-standard modules**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tweak your regex to use named capture group only once:

```py
(?P<time>\d{4}-\d{4})(?:(?= DAILY)|(?<=DAILY \d{4}-\d{4}))
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GcRhkK/1)

`(?:(?= DAILY)|(?<=DAILY \d{4}-\d{4}))` uses an alternation to apply condition of matching  `DAILY` after `time` or else it uses a lookbehind to ensure presence of `DAILY`  before the `time`.

Comment: I didn't want to use non-standard `regex` module, so thank you very much for this :)

Comment: You're welcome. It was important to know for me before reopening incorrect dupe since that option uses **non-standard regex module**

Comment: Edited original question to emphasize that I want to use standard modules only.

Comment: Perfect, that will be very helpful to avoid someone accidentally marking it dupe again.